# Compatible date formats for browser

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to display "**dd-mm-yyyy**" date format using the following method

```
document.getElementById('engStartDate').value=endDate.toLocaleDateString('en-IN',options);
```

But i am not getting the required format in chrome

Chrome  : Jun 11, 2016

Firefox : 11-Jun-2016

Comment: I my case it's not  working in chrome but working in firefox

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might not directly answer your question, but I suggest you give [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) a try. It's a Javascript library that allows you to manipulate and format dates and has saved my hide more than once. In your case you would do something like

```
document.getElementById('engStartDate').value = moment(endDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY);
```

Comment: Yeah, i strongly recommend that you use momentjs

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to do it manually or use a lib.
I write an example of formate data-time.

```js
var datetimeFormat = function ( datetime, formatStr) {
        var obj = null;
        if (({}).toString.call(datetime) === '[object Date]') {
            obj = datetime;
        } else {
            datetime = +datetime || 0;
            datetime = datetime < +new Date() / 100 ? datetime * 1000 : datetime;
            obj = new Date(datetime);
        }
        var str = formatStr;
        var Week = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wen', 'Tur', 'Fri', 'Sat'];

        str = str.replace(/yyyy|YYYY/, obj.getFullYear());
        str = str.replace(/yy|YY/,('0' + obj.getYear() % 100).slice(-2));
        var month = obj.getMonth() + 1;
        str = str.replace(/MM/, ('0' + month).slice(-2));
        str = str.replace(/M/g, month);

        str = str.replace(/w|W/g, Week[obj.getDay()]);

        str = str.replace(/dd|DD/, ('0' + obj.getDate()).slice(-2));
        str = str.replace(/d|D/g, obj.getDate());

        str = str.replace(/hh|HH/, ('0' + obj.getHours()).slice(-2));
        str = str.replace(/h|H/g, obj.getHours());
        str = str.replace(/mm/, ('0' + obj.getMinutes()).slice(-2));
        str = str.replace(/m/g, obj.getMinutes());

        str = str.replace(/ss|SS/, ('0' + obj.getSeconds()).slice(-2));
        str = str.replace(/s|S/g, obj.getSeconds());
        return str;
    }

document.getElementById('engStartDate').value = datetimeFormat(new Date(), 'dd-MM-yyyy')
```

```html
<input type='text' id='engStartDate'/>
```

Comment: Expressions like `obj.getMinutes() > 9 ? obj.getMinutes().toString() : '0' + obj.getMinutes())` are very much simper as `('0' + obj.getMinutes()).slice(-2)` which avoids calling the same method 3 times in one expression.

Comment: @RobG Yes, that's better and more elegant. Very smart, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[*Date.prototype.toLocaleString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.tolocaledatestring) doesn't take any arguments and the result is entirely implementation dependent.

If you want a particular format, you can use a library but it's not hard to write a simple function to output dd-mm-yyyy format:

```js
function toDMY(d) {
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'')+n}
  return z(d.getDate()) + '-' + z(d.getMonth()+1) + '-' + d.getFullYear();
}

document.write(toDMY(new Date()));
```

There is also the [*ECMAScript Internationalization API 1.0 (ECMA-402)*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/#sec-8) (also on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl)), however it's not well supported yet.